# Why the optimal value that minimizes a function does not satisfy condition?

Tags: optimization, proof-explanation, stochastic-analysis, economics, operations-research

I have found a solved example of *A Stochastic Two-Period Model with No Setup Cost* that has a lot of complicated calculations to arrive to the solution.

In the following example, $c=$cost of ordering, $h=$cost of holding and $p=$shortage cost.

[image]

The part where things start to complicate, is when making the substitution of $y_1^0$ into $C_1(x_1)$.

Clearly will not be an easy calculation by hand since $C_1$ has this function $L$, that it's evaluated with diferent arguments, which are two integrals.

I am not sure what form the argument of $\displaystyle \min_{y_1\ge x_1}\{\dots\}$ will have, nor what would be best to do next.  My book mentions this *OR Courseware* but since I have the pdf file book I don't have the disk? is refering to.

And my question is what can I do here in order to find the optimal $y_1^0$ without having to deal with lots and lots of calculations by hand?

Any suggestions are very appreciated.

[image]

The $C_1(x_1):$
[image]

The $L(z):$
[image]

## edit.

Following the comment of Larry, I substitute $y_1^0$ in the equation equal to zero (below the $C_1(x_1)$ definition in the image).

I assumed $y_1^0=5$ to be the optimal and this is what I got

$$-15+(15+10)\frac{5}{10}+(10-15)\Phi(5-2)+(15+10)\int_0^{3}\Phi(5-\xi)\phi_D(\xi)d\xi $$ $$=more\ calculations$$ $$=-\frac {11}{8}$$ This is different than $0$, which I don't understand why, the equation should have had the value $0$ because the book mentioned the optimal was $y_1^0=5$ and not $y_1^0=6$. Also the optimal should satisfy the equation equal to zero, but does not.

I really don't see what am I doing wrong? I did check twice the calculations of the expression and found no errors.

Comment: This is an inventory-theory problem, and it might be useful to you to look into some books or online resources about that topic. This model seems to be a 2-period version of the [newsvendor problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newsvendor_model); maybe that's a good place to start. But as your question is written now, it's not really clear what you are asking. Can you formulate your question more precisely and specifically?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 thank you. I have edited my question.

Comment: You do not need to solve the min by looping over $y_1$ values; the next part of the text ("it can be shown that...") gives you an equation that the optimal $y_1^0$ satisfies. You probably can't solve it like $y_1^0 = $ [something]; you'll have to solve that equation numerically.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 got it, so I should plug in $y_1^0=5,6$ into the equation equal to 0, and one of them will fail and the other will make the equation =0 and that would be the optimal, right?

Comment: I'm not quite sure ...

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 my common sense says I am right.

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand/ know about this topic but I have some ideas about the possible answer or how to disentangle the problems.

The optimal value of $y_1^0$ is $5.42$, as they compute in the example. However, they don't use the general equation:
[image]
But, the equation for the case of a uniform distribution:
[image]
In fact you can use the first equation (I did it) and obtain the same result. I give you some middle steps:
$$-15 + \frac{25y_1^0}{10} - 5 \frac{y_1^0-y_2^0}{10} + 25 \int_0^{y_1^0-y_2^0} \frac{y_1^0-\xi}{10}\frac{1}{10}d\xi = 0.$$
After substituting $y_2^0=2$ and some computations you reach:
$$-\frac{29}{2} + 2 y_1^0 + \frac{{y_1^0}^2}{8}=0,$$
with the only positive solution being $y_1^0 = 5.4164$. However, I imagine $y_1^0$ needs to be an integer, so he substitutes $C_1(x_1)$ for either $y_1^0=5$ and $y_1^0=6$ (the nearest points) to find which of them is the one that gives a smaller value. You can try to see if you can get this.
I computed $L(z)$ and I get:
$$L(z)=p\int_z^{10}  \frac{\xi-z}{10} d\xi + h \int_0^z \frac{z-\xi}{10}d\xi = \dots = \frac{p}{20} \left(10^2 - 20z\right) + \frac{z^2}{20} (p+h) = 5 (15-3z + \frac{z^2}{4}),$$
in case it is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you I appreciated your answer. The things is that it's supposed that calculations should be easy using the formula that comes after _It can be shown that $C_1(x_1)$ has a unique minimum_ because the optimal value $y^0_1=5$ or $y^0_1=6$ should satisfy the eq. equal to $0$. Wlog i assumed it was  $y^0_1=5$ (which is indeed the optimal) so it was supposed to get $0=0$ istead of $\frac{-11}{8}=0$ as shown in the **edit** of my question